# how to call/using geofield in a custom module

Tags: forms, location

I`m trying to use the geofield module, and load it with google maps widget in one my custom forms.

Yet i can't find any way to use the form api to display this field.

```
$form['geofield'] = array(
'#title' => 'geofield',
'#type' => 'geofield',
);
```

Any suggestion is welcome, i don't mind reading some docs.

Answer (score 2):

Geofield module is rather complex module which adds a lat/long fieldset and so many other stuff such as adding new fields, validation, etc.

Anyway, you can create a latitude and longitude input field using the `#type => 'geofield_latlon'`.

```
$form['geofield'] = array(
  '#title' => 'geofield',
  '#type' => 'geofield_latlon',
);
```

Note that this will return a generic longitude latitude form. NOT a Google Maps choose-location field.
See [geofield.elements.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/geofield.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/geofield.elements.inc) for more information on how this element is validated and themed.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that the above element is available in the 7.x-2.x branch.

Comment: Geofield_latlon doesn't seem to show anything either, its like nothing happends, what ever the type i`m trying to use.

Comment: My bad... I've installed 7.1 geofield module instead of the 7.2 branch. Now i'd have the latlon field.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the branch. 2.x branch has proximity filters as well, so I'm using that version in all my sites. Did `geofield_latlon` work ?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work now. Next step would be the map. I figured out i needed to install geofield gmap module to be able to have the widget for it. Any idea, how i would call that widget?

Comment: the only type i can find in the geofield_gmap files is geofield_gmap